# Requesting a fresh access token via google.accounts.oauth2 when using Google APIs in Javascript

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-signin, google-identity

According to this documentation, https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/use-token-model , which says:

> Token expiration
> By design, access tokens have a short lifetime. If the access token expires prior to the end of the user's session, obtain a new token by calling requestAccessToken() from a user-driven event such as a button press.

This steers us away from using a refresh token.  That is **Question 0**: when should a refresh token be used?

My app is a web app and users stay signed in for a long time -> longer than access token expiry time, which seems to be one hour.  To make it a little easier to continually fetch fresh access tokens as they are required, I wrote this code below.

It is intended to enable me to make statements like:

```
const provider = new GoogleAccessTokenProvider(clientId)
const scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly"]
provider.getTokenWithScopes(scopes)
    .then(token => {
        console.log(token)
    }).catch(e => {
        console.log(e)
    })
```

It seems like I have to do a lot of uninteresting stuff in this code, so I have many questions about it, listed below:

**Question 1** - It stores the token response from `google.accounts.oauth2` in local storage.  Is this the kind of thing Google intended us to do - store the access token locally?

**Question 2** - It manages token expiry (with a ten second buffer).  Again, is this something Google intend us to concern ourselves with?  Is there a lib that does this automatically?

**Question 3** - If calls `requestAccessToken()` with no prompt if the access token has the required scopes, but it is expired.  This flashes up the Google consent dialog for a second, then it disappears.  This seems to me to be where a refresh token would be handy.
Anyway, it works, but this flash up of the consent dialog is not great UX - is this what Google intended us to do?

**Question 4** - It calls `initTokenClient` for every `requestAccessToken()`, because `scopes` are bound to this call.  Seems odd to me - is this what Google intended us to do?

Anyway, here is the code:

```
class LocalStorage {
    getItem(key: string): string | null {
        return window.localStorage.getItem(key)
    }

    setItem(key: string, value: string): void {
        return window.localStorage.setItem(key, value)
    }
}

class TokenResponseStorage {
    constructor(private readonly localStorage = new LocalStorage()) {
    }

    getItem(key: string): WrappedGoogleAccessTokenResponse | null {
        const value = this.localStorage.getItem(key)
        if (value === null) {
            return null
        }
        return JSON.parse(value)
    }

    setItem(key: string, value: WrappedGoogleAccessTokenResponse): void {
        this.localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value))
    }
}

interface WrappedGoogleAccessTokenResponse {
    _type: "wrapped.google.access.token.response"
    expiresAtMillis: number
    tokenResponse: google.accounts.oauth2.TokenResponse
}

export class GoogleAccessTokenProvider {
    private readonly expiryMarginMillis = 1000 * 10 // ten seconds before expiry

    constructor(private readonly clientId: string,
                private readonly storage = new TokenResponseStorage(),
                private readonly storageKey = 'docsndata.google.access.token') {
    }

    async getTokenWithScopes(scopes: string[]): Promise<string> {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            const wrappedToken = this.storage.getItem(this.storageKey)
            if (wrappedToken && scopes.every(s => wrappedToken.tokenResponse.scopes.includes(s))) {
                if (this._hasSufficientExpiry(wrappedToken)) {
                    resolve(wrappedToken.tokenResponse.access_token)
                } else {
                    this._promptForToken(scopes, 'none').then(resolve)
                }
            } else {
                this._promptForToken(scopes, 'consent').then(resolve)
            }
        })
    }

    private _hasSufficientExpiry(token: WrappedGoogleAccessTokenResponse): boolean {
        return token.expiresAtMillis - this.expiryMarginMillis > Date.now()
    }

    private async _promptForToken(scopes: string[], prompt: "none" | "consent"): Promise<string> {
        const that = this
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            const tokenClient = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
                client_id: this.clientId,
                scope: scopes.join(' '),
                callback: function (tokenResponse) {
                    that._storeTokenResponse(tokenResponse)
                    resolve(tokenResponse.access_token)
                }
            })
            tokenClient.requestAccessToken({prompt})
        })
    }

    private _storeTokenResponse(tokenResponse: google.accounts.oauth2.TokenResponse) {
        const wrappedTokenResponse: WrappedGoogleAccessTokenResponse = {
            _type: "wrapped.google.access.token.response",
            expiresAtMillis: Date.now() + parseInt(tokenResponse.expires_in) * 1000,
            tokenResponse
        }
        this.storage.setItem(this.storageKey, wrappedTokenResponse)
    }
}
```

Comment: Answering #4, you can reuse the client returned by `initTokenClient()`. This is done in the Google [example code](https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/migration-to-gis#the_new_way). That code also implies the answer to #2 is to get a new access token when an API request fails due to an invalid token.